# Sorting rows and columns in a matrix by numerical dimnames

Tags: r, matrix

I have a sparse matrix whose rows and columns names are numbers.
I need to sort rows and columns so that they are increasing.
However, dimnames can only be stored as characters, not integers or numbers, so that sorting dimnames does not give increasing sorting but rather treats numbers as words and sorts them alphabetically (for example, 10000001 comes before 1001).

Every time I try to change the type of the dimnames I get this error:

```
Error in dimnamesGets(x, value) : 
  invalid dimnames given for “dgCMatrix” object
```

Is there a way around this? Are there different types of matrices that allow for numerical dimnames?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a numeric conversion *outside of the matrix* to get the right order, then use that ordering on the character-class dimnames to sort. For example:

```
my_colnames = c("1", "11",  "2", "10", "12")
my_col_order = order(as.numeric(my_colnames))
my_colnames[my_col_order]
[1] "1"  "2"  "10" "11" "12"
# sorted correctly even though still character class
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I got to the point or ordering them outside the matrix, but I don't understand how to use that order to actually sort the matrix. Is that the last line in your answer? and how would I apply it to a matrix? Sorry if this is trivial, I'm confused

Comment: I mean, I managed to replicate all of your code, but I still can't sort rows and columns of the matrix accordingly

Comment: If you share a small reproducible example in your question, I can attempt to demonstrate on that.